# CPU - motherboard compatibilty issue

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, upgrade

I have an old PC, that has AMD Sempron CPU on 1 GHz in it. And it works fine. I would like to try to upgrade CPU with one of the old CPU's I have, that are slightly better than current one. Those are AMD Athlon 1,2 Ghz, and AMD Athlon 2 GHz.

Motherboard model is KT600-A (V1.0) (http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=360&MenuID=24&LanID=0)

And CPU's I have are present on CPU compatibility list for this motherboard (http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-ECS/KT600-A(V1.0).html).

Now, first i tried with Athlon 2 GHz and PC didn't turn on. I pressed power button, CPU fan spins for a sec and thats all.

Then I tried with Athlon 1,2 GHz and when I pressed power button, PC did turn on, CPU fan was spinning, I could hear reading from hard disk (on old hard disks its normal :), but no image on monitor.

Then I put back Sempron on 1 Ghz, that was initially there, and with this one everything works fine. (Just to mention, on motherboard, under the CPU socket is printed 'Sempron'.)

What could be the cause why didn't those CPU's work when they are on compatibility list for this motherboard? Could it maybe be power supply related issue?

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problems are:

1. BIOS needs to be updated. (Make sure you have 1.2c)
2. BIOS settings need to be returned to normal. (Make sure you didn't set a specific CPU voltage or frequency.)

Comment: So, as I have understood, upgrading newer CPU can require updating BIOS? I would like to put Athlon 2 GHz if possible. It is on compatibility list for this motherboard. But, as I said, when I put it, and try to turn PC on, nothing happened. PC doesn't turn on. Could that be because of BIOS? Should I maybe update BIOS with old CPU, that is working, and then try to place new one?

Comment: Yes, upgrading the CPU often requires a BIOS update. What BIOS version do you have?

Comment: BIOS version is 1.1c.

Comment: @Wlad That's your problem. You need 1.2c, according to the manufacturer.

Comment: OK, thanks for help, I will try to update BIOS tommorow and then will post the result here.

Comment: Its not because of outdated BIOS. I have updated/flashed BIOS to 1.2c version, everything run smoothly, but again everything same. I took a picture of CPU socket area, see here: [link](http://ge.tt/2aDE0RB1/v/0?c) .You can see that on motherboard is printed tag 'Sempron'. Could it be that only Sempron's will work with this motherboard? Or, could it maybe be power-supply related issue? I mean, does faster CPU require stronger power supply?

Comment: @Wlad Can you tell us *exactly* what CPU(s) you tried?

Comment: CPU's I have tried are: 1. AMD Athlon AXDA2000DKT3C 4137606280654 RIRGA 0232MPM,  and 2. AMD Athlon A1200AMS3C AXIA 0118DPDW 95718640371

Comment: You can see CPU's here:[link](http://ge.tt/6Q6ieRB1/v/0?c) and here:[link](http://ge.tt/1kO1gRB1/v/0?c)